# Global variable vs. many db queries

Tags: flask

I will have a sidebar that appears on almost every page of my web app. The sidebar will have some drop-downs, which will consist of a total of say, 1000 different options, which are pulled from the db. Rather than doing the query to get these choices on every page load, I think it makes more sense to just do the query once, say in my `config.py` and store them in a variable that my views have access to. Is this OK? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that, but then you'd need to restart your Flask server every time you wanted to update the sidebar.

I'd use some other form of caching here. You could use [Flask-Cache](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/) and [memoize](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#memoization) your query results. You can pick a nice long cache timeout, and then [clear the cached result](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/#deleting-memoize-cache) whenever you update the sidebar.